# Android removing of subitems from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have an adapter for my`RecyclerView`. Each item of adapter has `ImageView` and another adapter for `RecyclerView`, which also has `ImageView` for each item in. I must click on subitem and go to its detail view. In that view, when I click on REMOVE button, it must remove this subitem. So I have several problems:

1. I've implemented method in main adapter, which has two parameters: position in main list and position in sublist. That's how I try to remove it. The problem is that when I remove one subitem at one position, it removes same subitems in another positions (I use fake data and some of them are the same).
2. After removing of one subitem, when I try remove the second, it doesn't remove. I've checked in debug mode and seen that size of list of subitems becomes such as at beginning.

There's code of my adapter. In main adapter I have inner class for adapter with subitems:

```
public class PhotoWithDuplicatesAdapterTest extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoWithDuplicatesAdapterTest.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<MediaWithDuplicatesTest> mTests;
    private OnDuplicateClickListener mListener;

    public PhotoWithDuplicatesAdapterTest(Context context, List<MediaWithDuplicatesTest> tests) {
        mContext = context;
        mTests = tests;
    }

    public interface OnDuplicateClickListener {
        void onDuplicateClick(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.photo_with_duplicates_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(mTests.get(position).getPhoto())
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.mPhotoImageView);
        DuplicateAdapter adapter = new DuplicateAdapter(mContext, position, mTests.get(position).getDuplicates());
        adapter.setOnDuplicateClickListener(new DuplicateAdapter.OnDuplicateClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDuplicateClick(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition) {
                if (mListener != null) mListener.onDuplicateClick(photoPosition, duplicatePosition);
            }
        });
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        holder.mDuplicatesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        holder.mDuplicatesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTests.size();
    }

    public void setOnDuplicateClickListener(OnDuplicateClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void removeDuplicate(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition) {
        List<String> duplicates = mTests.get(photoPosition).getDuplicates();
        duplicates.remove(duplicatePosition);
        if (duplicates.size() == 0) {
            mTests.remove(photoPosition);
            notifyItemRemoved(photoPosition);
        } else notifyItemChanged(photoPosition);
    }

    public String getDuplicate(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition) {
        return mTests.get(photoPosition).getDuplicates().get(duplicatePosition);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.iv_photo) SquareImageView mPhotoImageView;
        @Bind(R.id.rv_duplicates) RecyclerView mDuplicatesRecyclerView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public static class DuplicateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DuplicateAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private Context mContext;
        private int mPhotoPosition;
        private List<String> mDuplicates;
        private OnDuplicateClickListener mListener;

        public DuplicateAdapter(Context context, int photoPosition, List<String> duplicates) {
            mContext = context;
            mPhotoPosition = photoPosition;
            mDuplicates = duplicates;
        }

        public interface OnDuplicateClickListener {
            void onDuplicateClick(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition);
        }

        @Override
        public DuplicateAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.duplicate_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DuplicateAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDuplicates.get(position))
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.mDuplicateImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDuplicates == null ? 0 : mDuplicates.size();
        }

        public void setOnDuplicateClickListener(OnDuplicateClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            @Bind(R.id.iv_duplicate) SquareImageView mDuplicateImageView;

            @OnClick(R.id.iv_duplicate)
            void onDuplicateClick() {
                if (mListener != null) mListener.onDuplicateClick(mPhotoPosition, getAdapterPosition());
            }

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's how I call removing of subitem (in `Activity`)

```
// implementing of DuplicatesFragment.OnRemoveListener
@Override
public void onRemove(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition) {
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment instanceof DuplicatesFragment) {
        DuplicatesFragment duplicatesFragment = (DuplicatesFragment) fragment;
        duplicatesFragment.removeDuplicate(photoPosition, duplicatePosition);
    }
}
```

And `removeDuplicate` method in `DuplicatesFragment`:

```
public void removeDuplicate(int photoPosition, int duplicatePosition) {
    if (mAdapter != null) mAdapter.removeDuplicate(photoPosition, duplicatePosition);
}
```

mAdapter - instance of `PhotoWithDuplicatesAdapterTest`. What am I doing wrong?

That's how it looks:
[image]

There's `MediaWithDuplicatesTest` object:

```
public class MediaWithDuplicatesTest {

    private String mPhoto;
    private List<String> mDuplicates;

    public String getPhoto() {
        return mPhoto;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        mPhoto = photo;
    }

    public List<String> getDuplicates() {
        return mDuplicates;
    }

    public void setDuplicates(List<String> duplicates) {
        mDuplicates = duplicates;
    }
}
```

Maybe, it will be helpful if I also post code of creating my test data and adapter:

```
private void populateRecyclerViewHolder() {
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mAdapter = new PhotoWithDuplicatesAdapterTest(getContext(), getFakeData());
    mAdapter.setOnDuplicateClickListener(this);
    mViewHolder.mPhotosWithDuplicatesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mViewHolder.mPhotosWithDuplicatesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private List<MediaWithDuplicatesTest> getFakeData() {
    List<MediaWithDuplicatesTest> fakeData = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fakeDuplicates = getFakeDuplicates();
    for (String fakeDuplicate : fakeDuplicates) {
        MediaWithDuplicatesTest fake = new MediaWithDuplicatesTest();
        fake.setPhoto(fakeDuplicate);
        fake.setDuplicates(fakeDuplicates);
        fakeData.add(fake);
    }
    return fakeData;
}

private List<String> getFakeDuplicates() {
    return new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CmBgofK7QzU/TVj3u3N1h2I/AAAAAAAADN8/OszBhGvvXRU/s640/tumblr_lg7h9gpbtP1qap9qio1_500.jpeg");
            add("http://www.newcastlewildflower.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/9fkUCY02te7bqobeZzdT9SEio1_500.jpg");
            add("http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/51cc46900bf5fe574293d49c4d9939e0ebfc8ee3_m.jpg");
            add("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CmBgofK7QzU/TVj3u3N1h2I/AAAAAAAADN8/OszBhGvvXRU/s640/tumblr_lg7h9gpbtP1qap9qio1_500.jpeg");
            add("http://www.newcastlewildflower.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/9fkUCY02te7bqobeZzdT9SEio1_500.jpg");
            add("http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/51cc46900bf5fe574293d49c4d9939e0ebfc8ee3_m.jpg");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Uhm, can we have a visual representation of the work flow? Its kind of hard to imagine what you trying to achieve.

Comment: @GPuschka I've edited my post. As you can see, on the screen we have list. Each item of list represents: ImageView (in grey backround) and another List (right of ImageView)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any thing that might break the logic from the provided code. Except maybe the implementation of MediaWithDuplicatesTest. How is it implemented?

Comment: @GPuschka I've edited my post. I've added MediaWithDuplicatesTest object and code, which I use to create data for displaying in RecyclerView in my Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right there we go. In the *private List getFakeData()* method you are passing the same list of *fakeDuplicates* to all the items in for the main adapter. Which means that they share the underlying data. Changes to it are reflected on all the views created from the data. Put the instantiation of the list inside the loop and see if that helps.

Comment: Wow. It helps with my first problem. Thanks! But the second problem is still here :(

Comment: Try to observe when and how the 'private void populateRecyclerViewHolder()' is called. It should only be called once but from the code seen and the description my guess is that its called somewhere in between removing a duplicate. Is the detail view an acitvity?

Comment: No. Detail view is a fragment

Comment: Yeah. You absolutely right. When I click on Remove button in detail view I call fragmentManager.popBackStack() which calls onCreateView of my ListFragment. In onCreateView I call populateRecyclerViewHolder. Thanks for help! You've done my day! :)